# Python - How do I find the text of all spans with the id of 'value' using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to get all of the text of the spans which have the class of 'value'.

---

I then need to get the online ISSN of the page by using the first 9 characters of the text. I don't need the ones with text ending in "(print)" but I do need the ones ending in "(online)

---

**Example**

```
<span class="bold">ISSN: </span>
<span class="value">0890-037X (Print)</span>
<span class="value">1550-2740 (Online)</span>
```

---

Here I would need to get "1550-2740" as it is the online ISSN.
I think I need to find all the spans, check the class and then check the text. If the text ends in "(online)" then I need to get the first 9 characters.

---

How do I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many of those `span`s are there in the page? Is it only this one?

Comment: There are about 25

Comment: But only the three in the example are in "<li class="entry1">"

Comment: So you can uniquely get those three `span` elements then.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_all` to extract the elements. Create a `generator` (or `list` if you want) which is just the `text` attribute of each of these. Filter out those which do not end in `"(Online)"` and slice them to just extract the ISBN. I have used a `generator` and `next()` to just get the first occurrence, but you could just use a list if you wanted all of them (if there are multiple).

Hope this works for the whole file!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("p.html").read(), "lxml")
txt = (t.text for t in soup.find_all("span", class_="value"))
isbn = next(t[:9] for t in txt if t.endswith("(Online)"))
```

which gives `isbn` as `'1550-2740'`.

Comment: @marmadukeandbob No problem, just accept (grey --> green arrow) then :)

Comment: How do I then get the image src in this:

Comment: <a href="//static.cambridge.org/covers/WET_0_0_0/weed_technology.jpg?send-full-size-image=true" target="_blank" class="image">
<img src="//static.cambridge.org/covers/WET_0_0_0/weed_technology.jpg" alt="Weed Technology" data-enable-cup-replacement="true">
</a>

Comment: It is in the div with a class of  "clearfix details-container"

Comment: @marmadukeandbob Sorry, one question per question! It becomes too confusing if you ask things in the comments! Please accept and just quickly start a new thread that describes this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be something like below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="value"):
    if "Online" in item.text:
        print(item.text.split()[0])
```

Output:

```
1550-2740
```